# How to bind jquery plugin with data from collection in Meteor

Tags: jquery, meteor

I want to use jquery jcountdown plugin but I have a problems.
Starting time for timer is stored in collection and it's necessary for plugin init.
I want to do something like:

```
  var time = SeqTimestamp.findOne({}).time;
  $('.countdown').countdown({date: new Date});
```

Rendered callback run once and doesn't see collection that not good point for me.
How I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

```
Template.whatever.rendered = function () {
  var self = this;
  self.autorun(function () {
    var data = SeqTimestamp.findOne({});
    if (data) {
      self.$('.countdown').countdown({date: data.time});
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with something like this:

```html
<template name="whatever">
    {{#with theTime}}
        {{> whatever2}}
    {{else}}
        <p>There is no time!</p>
    {{/with}}
</template>
```

```js
Template.whatever.helpers({
    theTime: function(){
        return SeqTimestamp.findOne()
    }
})
```

```html
<template name="whatever2">
    <div class="countdown"></div>
</template>
```

```js
Template.whatever2.rendered = function(){
    var theTime = this.data.theTime
    this.$('.countdown').countdown({date: theTime.time})
}
```